# How could I run java class in command line for a intellij project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: inline]

When I change dir to `hw1/out/production/hw1/com/poc` and run `java Main`

It gave me `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`

Comment: I wouldn't really blame java for the lack of simplicity here. You have a nice file structure setup to separate your source files from your class files. The only download is you'll have to refer to your class files by said file structure, this should be viewed as a benefit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run `java com.poc.Main` from `hw1/out/production/hw1/`